# Spring Boot Validate JSON Mapped via ObjectMapper GET @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, fasterxml

What's the simplest approach to validating a complex JSON object being passed into a GET REST contoller in spring boot that I am mapping with *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper*?

Here is the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductsController {

@GetMapping
public ProductResponse getProducts(
        @RequestParam(value = "params") String requestItem
) throws IOException {
    final ProductRequest productRequest =
            new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(requestItem, ProductRequest.class);

    return productRetriever.getProductEarliestAvailabilities(productRequest);
}}
```

DTO request object I want to validate:

```
public class ProductRequest {
private String productId;

public String getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductId(String productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}}
```

I was thinking of using annotations on the request DTO however when I do so, they are not triggering any type of exceptions, i.e. *@NotNull*. I've tried various combinations of using *@Validated* at the controller as well as *@Valid* in the *@RequestParam* and nothing is causing the validations to trigger.

Comment: How about Hibernate Validator? You can feed it the `productRequest` annotation with your favourite hibernate-validator annotations before doing any work on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my point of view, `Hibernate Bean Validator` is probably one of the most convenient methods to validate the `annotated` fields of a bean anytime and anywhere. It's like `setup` and `forget`

- Setup the Hibernate Bean Validator
- Configure how the validation should be done
- Trigger the validator on a bean anywhere

I followed the instructions in the documentation given [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted)

## Setup dependencies

I use Gradle so, I am going to add the required dependencies as shown below

```
// Hibernate Bean validator
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.2.4.Final')
```

## Create a generic bean valdiator

I setup a bean validator interface as described in the documentation and then use this to validate everything that is annotated

```
public interface CustomBeanValidator {
    /**
     * Validate all annotated fields of a DTO object and collect all the validation and then throw them all at once.  
     * 
     * @param object
     */
    public <T> void validateFields(T object); 
}
```

Implement the above interface as follow

```
@Component
public class CustomBeanValidatorImpl implements CustomBeanValidator {
    ValidatorFactory valdiatorFactory = null; 

    public CustomBeanValidatorImpl() {
        valdiatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(); 
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void validateFields(T object) throws ValidationsFatalException {
        Validator validator = valdiatorFactory.getValidator(); 
        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> failedValidations = validator.validate(object); 

        if (!failedValidations.isEmpty()) {
            List<String> allErrors = failedValidations.stream().map(failure -> failure.getMessage())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            throw new ValidationsFatalException("Validation failure; Invalid request.", allErrors);
        }
    }
}
```

## The Exception class

The `ValidationsFatalException` I used above is a custom exception class that extends `RuntimeException`. As you can see I am passing a message and a list of `violations` in case the DTO has more than one validation error.

```
public class ValidationsFatalException extends RuntimeException {
    private String message; 
    private Throwable cause;
    private List<String> details; 

    public ValidationsFatalException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    } 

    public ValidationsFatalException(String message, Throwable cause, List<String> details) {
        super(message, cause); 
        this.details = details;
    }

    public List<String> getDetails() {
        return details; 
    }
}
```

## Simulation of your scenario

In order to test whether this is working or not, I literally used your code to test and here is what I did

- Create an endpoint as shown above
- Autowire the `CustomBeanValidator` and trigger it's `validateFields` method passing the `productRequest` into it as shown below
- Create a `ProductRequest` class as shown above
- I annotated the `productId` with `@NotNull` and `@Length(min=5, max=10)`
- I used `Postman` to make a `GET` request with a `params` having a value that is `url-encoded` json body

Assuming that the `CustomBeanValidator` is autowired in the controller, trigger the validation as follow after constructing the `productRequest` object.

```
beanValidator.validateFields(productRequest);
```

The above will throw exception if any violations based on annotations used.

## How is the exception handled by exception controller?

As mentioned in the title, I use `ExceptionController` in order to handle the exceptions in my application.

Here is how the skeleton of my `exception handler` where the `ValidationsFatalException` maps to and then I update the message and set my desired status code based on exception type and return a custom object (i.e. the json you see below)

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler({SomeOtherException.class, ValidationsFatalException.class})
public @ResponseBody Object handleBadRequestExpection(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    if(ex instanceof CustomBadRequestException) 
        return new CustomResponse(400, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage()); 
    else 
        return new DetailedCustomResponse(400, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage(),((ValidationsFatalException) ex).getDetails()); 
}
```

#### Test 1

Raw `params = {"productId":"abc123"}` 
 
Url encoded `parmas = %7B%22productId%22%3A%22abc123%22%7D` 
Final URL: `http://localhost:8080/app/product?params=%7B%22productId%22%3A%22abc123%22%7D` 
Result: All good.

#### Test 2

Raw `params = {"productId":"ab"}` 
 
Url encoded `parmas = %7B%22productId%22%3A%22ab%22%7D` 
Final URL: `http://localhost:8080/app/product?params=%7B%22productId%22%3A%22ab%22%7D` 
Result:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": "Validation failure; Invalid request.",
    "details": [
        "length must be between 5 and 10"
    ]
}
```

You can expand the `Validator` implementation to provide a mapping of `field vs message` error message.

Comment: This is great! A couple things as I almost have this working like you but not quite there. Can you include the code for RuntimeException? I am getting back a 500 status code, how did you get 400? How did you populate the details field in the error response? Also a couple potential minor edits; looks like the constructor name is wrong in your code example of CustomBeanValidatorImpl? Finally, I believe you mean "extends RuntimeException" and not "implements RuntimeException"? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I meant `extend` not implement.
1) Added the `Exception` class 
2) Added the `Exception Controller` endpoint how the exception is handled and converted to `Bad Request`

You might also be able to make use of `Spring AOP` if you do not want to use `Hibernate Bean Validator` though, the bean validator is the way to go in my point of view.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
@RequestMapping("/products")
public ResponseEntity getProducts(
        @RequestParam(value = "params") String requestItem) throws IOException {

    ProductRequest request = new ObjectMapper().
            readValue(requestItem, ProductRequest.class);

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();

    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<ProductRequest>> violations
            = validator.validate(request);

    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}



public class ProductRequest {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3)
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

public String setId( String id) {
    return this.id = id;
    }
}
```